# 便利にタブ補完したい！（Railsのマイグレーションファイル名）

Tags: linux, bash

タブ補完についての質問です。
bashで、当該ファイル名を入力する場合に、タブ補完がしづらく困っています。

具体的には、
Railsのマイグレーションファイル名の形式が 20210101000000_xxx.rb といったものなので、
すでにマイグレーションファイルを作成してあるアプリケーションにおいて、
月日を跨いだ後に、短い時間にマイグレーションファイルを複数作成した場合に、
上10桁を手入力しないと、タブ補完で入力しきれずに困っています。

皆さん、アイデアをください！
例
・後方一致でtab補完する方法
・vimのファイルツリーを使って、db/migrate/ フォルダ下を矢印操作でファイル選択をする
など

```
20210101000000_xxx.rb #年月日時分秒_xxx.rb
```

Comment: 具体的にどう困っているのか (またはどう補完されたらうれしいのか) 辺りを書いておくと回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

なんらかのツールを入れてもいいのであれば、pecoを使うのはどうでしょう。
https://github.com/peco/peco にあるツールでファイル一覧から選択してRubyスクリプトが実行できるようになるはずです